# Navigate to anchor in loaded WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm implementing a Android native interface to a HTML5 content and are loading pages trough

```
webView.loadUrl("file://" + path);
```

That does displays right as intended, my problem is: I do has a list of available anchor links such:

```
#/tema/5eefaa35ca922dcd44366cfd0da81910
#/tema/e2f970027838177c49f83996970620d3
```

and I'm trying to navigate to the anchors at the loaded WebView but didn't get it:

My tries:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.location="+hashLink);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.hash="+hashLink);
```

But none works, at this point, I don't has the original link to use with a hashLink, and also I do want to avoid reloading the web content.